# How to install rubyracer gem on 10.10.3 OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I can't install this gem on my OSX when I run bundle install. Here is the log:

```
/Users/Storm1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@abc/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': 
You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError) and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. 
However, it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of v8 that is compatible with 3.11.8.17 installed. You may need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard location
thanks,
The Mgmt

from /Users/Storm1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@abc/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Storm1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@abc/gems/therubyracer-0.11.4 for inspection.Results logged to /Users/Storm1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@abc/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/therubyracer-0.11.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I installed many times but not successfully. Is there anyone here that has this problem?

Comment: Have you installed libv8? Are you using homebrew or another package manager?

Comment: I have installed libv8 with command: gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.12' but not successfully

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask is have you installed V8? Libv8 relies on the C V8 library.

Comment: Well, I haven't installed V8.

Comment: Get [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and do `brew install v8`

Comment: I installed it but I still got old errors